# Извлечение internal типа из стороннего пространства имён

Tags: c#, wpf

Я бы хотел иметь возможность устанавливать свойство `UIElement.IsMouseOver` для любого элемента. К сожалению, в отличии от `IsPressed`, оно readonly. Однако, есть internal метод `WriteFlag`, который элементарно извлекается через `Type.GetMethod`. Но запустить его (через `MethodInfo.Invoke`) не получится. В качестве одного из параметров он принимает значение перечисления `System.Windows.CoreFlags` (вот если бы это перечисление было в каком-нибудь классе, можно было бы извлечь через `Type.GetNestedType`).

Так вот, мне требуется получить этот тип в переменной Type. А дальше работаем, так думаю, через `Convert.ChangeType`.

Comment: Что вы сделать-то пытаетесь? Зачем вы пытаетесь сломать логику платформы?

Comment: Опишите подробно результат, которого хотите добиться. Наверняка есть решение всяких хаков.

Comment: @AGS17: Я понимаю, что пытаюсь идти в обход привычной логике и, как вы верно выразились, пытаюсь "сломать платформу"))) Однако, вполне вероятно, что найдётся какой-нибудь хак, который решит мой вопрос. В итоге мне нужна возможность самостоятельно задавать свойство `IsMouseOver` для объектов типа `UIElement` (которое, ещё раз, **readonly**).

Comment: @sp7: Тоже так считаю) А добиться я пытаюсь.. ну короче смотрите мой коммент выше.

Comment: Это может оказаться бесполезным, т. к. при установке флагов наверняка происходят дополнительные подстройки, которые простая смена флагов не сделает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выглядит бесполезной затеей. Но решить этот вопрос можно как-то так:

```
var coreFlagsType = typeof(UIElement).Assembly.GetTypes().First(t => t.Name.Equals("CoreFlags"));
var writeFlagMethod = typeof(UIElement).GetMethod("WriteFlag", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var isMouseOverCacheCoreFlag = Enum.Parse(coreFlagsType, "IsMouseOverCache");

// тут вместо button подсунуть наследника UIElement, для которого сетать MouseOver
writeFlagMethod.Invoke(button, new object[] { isMouseOverCacheCoreFlag, true });
```

Тоже думал сначала через `Convert.ChangeType()`. Но т.к. тип `CoreFlags` - `internal` - вываливался эксепшн.

Comment: Хотели вроде без хаков решение.

Comment: @sp7 без хаков? Это как? Может я о чем-то не знаю? :)

Comment: Ну можно попробовать событие `MouseEnter` сгенерировать, хотя я не уверен, что "заведется", нужно проверять.

Comment: @sp7 не завелось.

Comment: Через RaiseEvent можно. Но не во всех случаях получится) Например, ComboBoxItem (внутри ComboBox) такого события вообще не получает!

Comment: @AGS17: Спасибо за ваш ответ. Свою проблему я решил гораздо более изящно. Но за то теперь буду иметь ввиду как подобные вещи делаются.